# Issues with passing inputs in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been following Traversy media's Angular crash course. This is where the issue lies. I cannot get past this point as we need these items to style the button using this method. as soon as I save and pass these onto the local server it will not allow me to return and continues to say that there is an error even when I delete and reload causing me to delete the entire project and start all over.

file heading --> header.component.html

```
<header>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
   <app-button color="green" text="Add"></app-button>
</header>
```

file of where I need to change --> button.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

/* when added breaks entire program */
  @Input() text: string;
  @Input() color: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

It seems like there is something major that I am missing. In VS code it says the issue is where the comment is. BTW in the actual code, those are not typed in. I just wanted to show where they will go.

It is almost like the color and text do not exist to define.

Comment: Code looks fine..? Maybe something strange with your environment?

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add a singel quote

```
<app-button color="'green'" text="'Add'"></app-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct use

```html
<app-two [color]="'green'" [text]="'Add'"></app-two>
```

```
  @Input() color: string = '';
  @Input() text: string = '';
```